# Under exposed images when using webcam as a camera on an Emulator

Tags: camera, android-emulator, android-camera

I have been using android studio and its AVD for a long time. I have used the webcam as the back camera with no problems.

I had a working app that took a pictures with the phones camera and updated an image view with the returned bitmap thumbnail.

I then decided to try and use files rather than bitmaps to improve the quality of the image by following the following tutorial..

[Android tutorial: Taking Photos Simply](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html)

I did not manage to get it to work so reverted back to using the bitmap thumbnail.

My problem is, now when I use my mac book webcam to take a picture using the emulator, the image is so under exposed that it is returning just a black square (unless I am pointing it directly at a light source.

Has anyone any idea of what could have happened and how to fix it?

(I do not think this is related to my app as even when creating a new emulator and just running the built in camera app I get the same problem)